# How to use a different value for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto in the production environment

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, deployment, persistence

In my Java EE application, I always configure my `persistence.xml` file with this option :

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop">
```

It's really handy for tests. When I commit my code, persistence.xml is committed with this configuration. However, when I deploy to production, I don't want to drop my database.

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` for an enterprise application. It's better if you use [`Flyway`](https://vladmihalcea.com/flyway-database-schema-migrations/) for both production and integration tests.

That being said, even using an in-memory DB like H2 is not desirable. You can run integration tests on MySQL and PostgreSQL almost as fast as H2 if you map the data folder on [`tmpfs`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-run-integration-tests-at-warp-speed-with-docker-and-tmpfs/).

So, back to your problem. If you really need to recreate tables only on test env but not on production, then you need to use a Maven parameter for the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hbm2ddl.value}">
```

For the production profile, the value is:

```
<hbm2ddl.value>none</hbm2ddl.value>
```

While for the development profile (default), the value is:

```
<hbm2ddl.value>create-drop</hbm2ddl.value>
```

Comment: Thanks, Flyway seems to be the cleanest option !